# Button not found when push in Android

Tags: android

I have a problem. I have an UpdateActivity with a button, but when I click the "log out" button, nothing happens. I also have MainActivity that decides what view to show. Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivityBase {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    User user = new User();
    if(user.getLastUser() == null){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }else{
        if(user.getLastUser().getActive() == 0) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }else{
            setContentView(R.layout.profile);
        }
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

UpdateActivity.java

```
public class UpdateActivity extends Activity {

Button logout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profile);
    final  Intent  intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogout);

    logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FBLoginFragment.logout();
            User user = new User();
            user.disable();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's look like you never launch the Update Activity.
In your main Activity you're just changing the layout with  `setContentView(R.layout.profile);`
But your are not implementing the OnCLickListener on the button.

You should add the onCLikcListerner in your main activity, or best: You should launch the UpdateActivity depending on the user status and not changing the view of your main activity.

Comment: How Can i launch the UpdateActivity?

Comment: Intent  intent = new Intent(this, UpdateActivity.class); startActivity(intent);